# Why did Arthur Waley change the title in his translation of Journey to the West?

Tags: translation, title, chinese-language, journey-to-the-west, arthur-waley

[*Journey to the West*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West) is a 16th-century Chinese novel whose original title 西遊記 means (according to Wikipedia) "West-Wandering Chronicles". In Arthur Waley's well-known 1942 [English translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_(novel)), he changed the title to *Monkey: A Folk-Tale of China*. It's been published under a few variant titles, but always the title's focus is on the monkey rather than the journey.

**Why was the title changed in this translation?** Not all English translations have changed the title: *Journey to the West* seems more common for English versions. Does it relate to the chapters Waley chose to excise or keep during his abridgement - does the change in title reflect a change in focus of the story?

Comment: Not gonna lie, in very quick read I thought that said "Arthur Weasley". Okay, I'll go back to my SFF hole now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Journey to the West* is divided into three sections:

1. Chapters 1–7: the rebellion of Monkey (Sun Wukong) against the gods and his punishment by Buddha.
2. Chapters 8–12: the early life of Tripitaka (Tang Xuanzang) and his recruitment by Kuan-Yin.
3. Chapters 13–100: the recruitment of Tripitaka’s companions, their journey to India, and their return to China with the sutras.

Thus, 88% of the original novel is about the journey to the West, amply justifying its title.

Waley’s translation, however, substantially abridges the original. He included the whole of part 1 (Monkey’s rebellion) and part 2 (Triptaka’s recruitment), but from part 3 he selected eighteen of the eighty-eight chapters:

- Chapters 13–15: recruitment of Monkey and the Dragon Horse.
- Chapters 18–19: recruitment of Pigsy (Zhu Bajie).
- Chapter 22: recruitment of Sandy (Sha Wujing).
- Chapters 37–39: ‘The Lion Demon in the Kingdom of Crow-Cock’.
- Chapters 44–46: ‘The Cart-Slow Kingdom’.
- Chapters 47–49: ‘The River that Leads to Heaven’.
- Chapter 98: ‘The Goal Achieved’.
- Chapters 99–100: ‘The Eighty-first Calamity’.

Monkey’s rebellion thus constitutes nearly a quarter of Waley’s translation, and the particular episodes selected from the third section of the book further foreground the character:

> The episodes selected by Waley all highlight the Monkey as a hero who plays a vital role in using his own power or strategies to subdue demons and help the pilgrims successfully complete their mission. Waley’s reduction of *The Journey to the West* from one hundred chapters to thirty chapters makes an important change to the original story: to a large extent, the journey becomes the Monkey’s journey of self-development, whose growth and heroic behavior overshadow Tripitaka, the original protagonist.
>
> <sub>Hao Ji (2016). ‘[A Comparative Study of Two Major English Translations of *The Journey to the West*: *Monkey* and *The Monkey and the Monk*](https://doi.org/10.1163/23521341-12340027)’. *Journal of Chinese Humanities* 2:1, p.80.</sub>

Waley thus refashioned the book from the story of Tripitaka’s journey (in which Monkey plays a secondary role) into the story of Monkey’s rebellion and penance (in which Tripitaka plays a secondary role).

Comment: Perfect answer: I thought something like that might have been the reason. (Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_to_the_West#Synopsis) that the original is divided into *four* unequal parts, not three, where the fourth one is just chapter 100.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor: I followed Hu Shih, who writes "The story is originally in one hundred chapters which may be divided into three main parts." I don't see the point of making a separate part just for chapter 100, since the action immediately follows that of chapter 99.